# Ошибка при возведении в степень

Tags: c, gcc

Данный код выводит ошибочный ответ, но только когда:

- a = 3
- используется переменная, а не константа

-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){
    int a = 3;
    int b = pow( 10, a -1 );            // 100
    double c = pow( 10, a -1 );            // 100
    int d = pow( 10, 2 );                // 100
    int e = a * pow( 10, a-1 );            // 300
    int f = a * (int)pow( 10, a-1 );    // 300

    printf( "%d\n", b );                // выводит 99
    printf( "%0.15f\n", c );            // выводит 100.000000000000000
    printf( "%d\n", d );                // выводит 100
    printf( "%d\n", e );                // выводит 299
    printf( "%d\n", f );                // выводит 297

    return 0;
}
```

Почему это происходит?

Проверял на gcc 4.7.0 и g++ 4.7.0

Comment: gcc-4.3.4 и gcc-4.6.3 без ошибок.

Comment: Проверил gcc-4.7, gcc-4.6, gcc-4.4, icc-12.1.5 в Убунте - все работает правильно.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[@purple-Sketch](/users/8534/purple-sketch), Спасибо за отличный вопрос !

Похоже на то, что результат `pow()` (вычисления в double) чуть меньше 100, а `printf ("%0.15f)` *округляет* результат (по крайней мере в MinGW 32-bit на Windows 64-bit (*привет Б. Гейтсу?*)).

При преобразовании `double -> int` дробная часть отбрасывается.

При вычислении `int d = pow( 10, 2 );` компилятор все вычисляет сам (в ассемблерном коде нет иструкции  `call   _pow`)

При вычислении `int e = a * pow( 10, a-1 );` `a` перед умножением преобразуется в `double`, поэтому результат 299.

Windows 7

```
c:/Users/avp/src/cc/hashcode $ gcc powerr.c 
c:/Users/avp/src/cc/hashcode $ ./a
99
100.000000000000000
100
299
297
c:/Users/avp/src/cc/hashcode $ gcc --version
gcc.exe (GCC) 3.4.5 (mingw-vista special r3)
```

Ubuntu

```
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ gcc powerr.c -lm
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ ./a.out 
100
100.000000000000000
100
300
300
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS \n \l

avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ gcc --version
gcc.real (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1) 4.4.3
```

Ubuntu стоит на 64-bit машине в 64-bit ОС.

Comment: но ведь double, если я не ошибаюсь, можеть содержать до 15 знаков после запятой. Если выводить их все, почему происходит округление?

Comment: Добавил проверочку

        double delta = pow(10,a-1) - 100.0;
        printf ("delta = %e %s\n",delta, delta == 0? "eq":"ne");

получил

    delta = -6.938894e-018 ne

Вот и ответ. Так в M$ видят pow().

Comment: @purple-Sketch Слово "округление" Вы использовали неправильно. В C при выполнении 

    int b = pow( 10, a -1 );

применяется не округление (round), а отбрасывание дробной части. А поскольку `pow(a, b)` в общем случае это `exp(log(a)*b)`, то результат вполне закономерен и предсказуем. Случай 

    int d = pow( 10, 2 );

как отметил @avp -- проделки оптимизатора.

Answer (score -1):

Потому что приоритет у операции возведения в степень.
Да и не стоит делать вычисления в на месте аргументов функции, предполагаю что сначала возводиться в степень 2 (а-1) а потом еще делается минус 1

а какая реакция если вместо а=3 будет а=5 ?

Comment: при любом значении a кроме 3, при использовании константы ( как в 'd' ) работает как и ожидалось.

приоритет думаю тут роли не играет. в выражении ( a * pow( 10, a-1) ) pow вычисляется только раз.

Comment: pow - это не оператор, а функция. А делать вычисления и т.п. в аргументах при вызове функции - нормальная практика.