# Выбрать число в конце произвольной строки

Tags: c++, arduino, esp8266

char* topic возвращает строку с содержимым "текст/текст/число(от 0-128)"
Как можно считать число в конце строки в int?

Comment: А нельзя ли записать эту строку в виде `std::string`?

Comment: вместо char? Я получаю char* topic от готовой библиотеки mqtt. Или я не так понял?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если же `topic` должен быть с типом только `char*`, но при этом число число достаточно маленькое, то тогда можно просто пройтись по строке с конца с помощью цикла `for`, затем заносить в число-результат каждую цифру с конца, умножая её на 10^(число цифр вместе с данной цифрой).

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstring>

int main() {
    const char* text = "text/text/124";
    int res = 0, digits = 0;
    // int degree = 1;
    for (size_t i = strlen(text) - 1; text[i] != '/'; i--) {
      if (isdigit(text[i])) { // если цифра, то выполняем прибавление
          res += (text[i] - '0') * pow(10, digits++);
          // res += (text[i] - '0') * degree;
          // degree *= 10;
      }
    }
    std::cout << res;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Отлично работает! Один момент, можно проверку добавить что в конце получаемой строки text действительно число, а то если попадает текст он также принимает числовые значения.

Comment: `pow(10, digits++)` — неоправданное привлечение арифметики с плавающей точкой в целочисленную задачу. Даже если аргументы целочисленные и точный результат возведения в степень представим типом `double`, то не гарантируется, что этот точный результат будет получен. И недружелюбные реализации `pow` [существуют](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/137699).

Comment: @Diminator по идее Ваша строка всегда имеет вид, указанный в условии, т.е. нецифр справа быть не должно. Но всё же на всякий пожарный добавлю проверку на цифру

Comment: @wololo спасибо за информацию, довольно необычно это дело выглядит. Я думал, в основном `pow()` в плюсах более-менее стабильно работает, ан нет...
В общем, добавил вариант, не зависящий от double

Comment: Если значение `text[i]` не представимо типом `unsigned char` и не равно `EOF`, то поведение выражения `isdigit(text[i])` не определено.

Answer (score 0):

```
uint8_t get_number(char* topic) {
   uint8_t n = 0;
   while (topic[n] != '/') ++n;
   ++n;
   while (topic[n] != '/') ++n;
   ++n;
   uint8_t result = 0;
   while (topic[n] != 0) result = result * 10 + topic[n] - '0';
   return result;
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: `uint8_t n = 0;` А  если длина строки, например, 1000 символов?

Comment: @wololo в Arduino не очень большая RAM, чтобы работать с длинными строками.

Comment: я правильно понимаю что данный пример разбирает основываясь на нахождении "/"?

Comment: @Diminator согласно ТЗ.