# Ошибка в цикле while() в C++

Tags: c++, codeblocks

Я столкнулся с проблемой в цикле while() на C++, я делаю одну задачу на етом [сайте](https://eolymp.com/), код к етой задаче я написал, но один кусок кода немного неправильный.
 Есть две переменные `a` и `l`, они выполняют следующую функцию:
 `a=pow(10, k=k-1);`
 `l=pow(10, h=h-1);`
 (Переменные `k` и `h` - равны числу цифр в числе `n`)
 Представляем, что `n = 123` значит переменные `k` и `h` равны `3`, а при условии выполнения функций `a`, `l` будет:
 `a=pow(10, 3=3-1);`
 `l=pow(10, 3=3-1);`
 Тоесть получается, что переменные `a` и `l` должны приобретать значение типа `10` во `2`-ю степень, то есть `100`, но когда я проверяю значение этих переменных, оно не равно `100`, а равно чему-то `99`. И из-за этого фрагмента кода, весь код идет коту под хвост. Можете ли вы сказать мне, почему этот фрагмент кода ведет себя таким образом?

Comment: [Неоправданное привлечение арифметики с плавающей точкой в целочисленную задачу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/137699).

Comment: [Вычисления на числах с плавающей точкой не работают](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/417453).