# Как узнать длину числа без использования строк?

Tags: c++, c, алгоритм, функции

Например, на вход в функцию поступает число 12345. Результатом будет 5. Даже если число отрицательное, например, -1234567, то результатом будет 7.

Comment: на какой  вход ?  Если это поток, то можно даже не считать число.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan а если это бинарное представление в потоке а не десятчиное?

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, в метках же написано алгоритм и функции

Comment: @Владимир Клыков, вы лучше не повторяйте чужие ответы. А число 12345 никак не бинарное представление.(а если так, то  и  ваш ответ не верный, потому что пока нет числа)

Comment: @Pingvy,  И что?...  любое решение  можно выполнить в функции....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для работы с log10 и abs необходимо подключить библиотеку math.h (Для типа int работает корректно)

```
int lenNum(int value)
{
    return (value != 0) ? (int)(log10(abs(value))) + 1 : 1;
}
```

Если же входные данные типа long или long long, то лучше обойтись обычным же стопудовым вариантом - через циклы. (Выше коллеги представили множество подобных решений).

```
int lenNumLL(long long value)
{
    int len = 0;

    do
    {
        value /= 10;
        len++;
    } while (value);

    return len;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Я думаю, это самое оптимизированное решение с наименьшей вычислительной сложностью.

Comment: @Pingvy, нет, это наоборот _  сложнее и не без побочных эффектов.  Если вы не пишете цикл, это еще не значит, что  выполняется быстрее.

Comment: Неоправданное привлечение арифметики с плавающей точкой в целочисленную задачу. На некоторых входных данных [ответ неверен](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ec1e6a42f85655bc).

Comment: @wololo, согласен, на больших значениях функция захлебнулась).

Comment: @wololo Мне тоже не нравится дробный `log10`, но, справедливости ради, в ответе стоит `int`, а в своем примере вы его поправили на `long`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, `int` также не даёт гарантий получения корректного результата. Просто я, к сожалению, не могу найти онлайн-компилятор, имеющий те же проблемы с реализацией математических функций, что и в [этом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/137699).

Comment: 1) Да, вариант с логарифмом проигрывает по производительности способу с циклом. [Тест-1](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d55f0e0beb60b118), [тест-2](https://rextester.com/NYXT70524). 2) `Для типа int работает корректно` На некоторых входных данных ответ для типа `int` [также неверен](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0348c6bf3ba1e186).

Answer (score 4):

```
int length(int n) {
    if (n == 0) return 1;
    int l = 0;
    while(n) {
        l++;
        n /= 10;
        }
    return l;
    }
```

Или так:

```
int length(int n) {
    int l = 1;
    for(; n/=10; ++l);
    return l;
    }
```

Comment: Простите что так нагло утащил ваш код, но имхо - do while  красивше :)

Comment: Да да :) так прям оно!

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков Нет, там все же была ошибка. Сейчас подумаю...

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков Теперь можно смотреть :)

Comment: Блин, ляпота :) не додумался...  седин мне в голову....

Answer (score 4):

```
int length(int n) {
    int l = 0;
    do {
        l++;
        n /= 10;
    } while(n);
    return l;
}
```

Comment: Или даже так `int l = 0; do { l++; } while (n /= 10);`

Comment: @avp Да =) уже додумался до такого :) но через for как в примере выше - красивше

Answer (score 1):

Еще есть варианты:

```
size_t foo1(const int  n)
{ return std::to_string(n).size() - size_t(n < 0); }

size_t foo2(const int n)
{
    std::ostringstream out;
    out << n;
    return out.str().size() - size_t(n < 0);
}
//...
```

Но лучше с делением на основание.

Comment: Еще в одну строчку: `std::snprintf(nullptr, 0, "%d", std::abs(n))`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat,  не  просто так я поставил многоточие.  Верно _ вариантов  много.

Answer (score 1):

Перевожу свой комментарий в ответ:

```
int n = 42;
int len = std::snprintf(nullptr, 0, "%d", n) - (n < 0);
```

Comment: 1) `std::snprintf ... не требует выделения памяти в куче` Не помешает какой-нибудь пруф. [Здесь не столь категоричны](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28570170). 2) UB, если `n == INT_MIN`.

Comment: (1) Эксперимент показывает что не требует: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/v6j6EMMq9 , но фразу из ответа лучше уберу. Так-то и `std::to_string` наверное не требует, строка-то короткая... (2) Починил.